# mule dataweave invoking a spring bean

Tags: mule, resourcebundle, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I have a spring bean defined to handle the resource bundle of my app as follows:

```
<spring:bean id="renewMobileEngagementApiMessages" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <spring:property name="basename" value="messages/renew-mobile-engagement-api-messages"></spring:property>
    <spring:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></spring:property>
    <spring:property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"></spring:property>
</spring:bean>
```

In my app I can access it in a variable or logger object for example with the following MEL command:

```
#[app.registry.renewMobileEngagementApiMessages.getMessage('error.clic_unavailable.description', null, sessionVars.REQUESTED_LOCALE)]
```

It returns correctly my property as expected, no problem until here.

The problem is that now I need to access my properties in a dw:transform-message and I can't figure out how to do it. I tried with a global-function but I didn't got how to access my "renewMobileEngagementApiMessages" object reference to then call the "getMessage" method.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you define this through property placeholder https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/configuring-properties#properties-files and then access properties either using ${..} outside dataweave or as `p('propName')` inside dataweave?

Comment: Because I need internationalisation. I have a properties file for each language and I access them using the spring resource bundle.

Answer (score 0):

just put the message in a flowVar or the payload before the dataweave component with a MEL and access the payload/flowVar in your dataweave.

here is a example where i load my spring bean in payload right before i access it my dataweave:

```
<mule>
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="foo" name="foo" class="java.lang.String">
            <spring:constructor-arg value="this is foo." />
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>

    <flow name="test-flow">
        <set-payload value="#[app.registry.foo]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload>
<![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    foo: payload
}]]>
</dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Thanks but that's exactly the solution I want to avoid. I will need to do this in multiple places lot's of times, it's not practical to put my translations into vars each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the property in a flow variable before the dataweave component and call this `flowVars` in `dataweave` using `flowVars.variableName`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access any System or Spring properties with the operator 'p()'

Example:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    mulehome: p('mule.home')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference any Property (System or Spring) that exists in the server while DataWeave is processing your transformation, to do so use the p('prop_name') function.